# Degel Machane Efrayim

Tags: jewish-books

My friends and I were learning about the way that the Jews camped in the wilderness, and someone heard about a book called Degel Machane Efrayim.
Does anyone know who wrote it and where I can find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @DoubleAA rightly pointed out, there's more than one work called Degel Machane Ephraim. The one I'm most familiar with - and what I think is the most well-known one - is a Chassidic work by [Rabbi Moshe Chaim Ephraim of Sudkilov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Chaim_Ephraim_of_Sudilkov), grandson of the Baal Shem Tov (and, incidentally, is an ancestor of mine...). His book in Hebrew can be accessed [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/3723). It's a commentary on the Pentateuch.

Other such works are by [Rabbi Ephraim Laniado](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%90%D7%93%D7%95), chief rabbi of Aleppo (his book in Hebrew can be found [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/1351)) and by Rabbi Ephraim Shteinberg, who was a rabbi at [RIETS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi_Isaac_Elchanan_Theological_Seminary) (his book, a halachic work, in Hebrew can be accessed [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/13156)).

Note that these three are the only ones listed, both in Hebrewbooks and in Otzar Hachochmah.

Comment: What is the Pentateuch

Comment: @ylevy Five books of Moshe/חמישה חומשי תורה